# VPN Server freezing after client connection

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, nat

I have a virtual Windows Server 2012 R2 and there I have a VPN Server. So, client can connect to this server and get an access to the Internet. Client can ping, but if one trying to load a webpage, VPN server freezing and I have to reload WinSer. Even VNC doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Here's some info: 
[image]
[image]

Also I have this error in Event Log: `VPN IP Addressing monitor has gone from HEALTHY state to UNHEALTHY state on 6/3/2017 at 2:19 PM on WIN-344VU98D3R. The failure heuristic IDs for state change of VPN IP Addressing are 40030001.`

Comment: Probably an hardware and not a configuration issue, please run a memtest and then a CPU and disks stress test like stresslinux.

Comment: > 
Probably an hardware and not a configuration issue, please run a memtest and then a CPU and disks stress test like stresslinux 

I agree with this.